# can any one find the error in my algorithm. It is saying "int object is not iterable"

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, error-handling, runtime-error, typeerror

> Alice is playing an arcade game and wants to climb to the top of the leaderboard and wants to track her ranking. The game uses Dense Ranking, so its leaderboard works like this:
>
> The player with the highest score is ranked number 1 on the leaderboard.
>   Players who have equal scores receive the same ranking number, and the next player(s) receive the immediately following ranking number.
>   For example, the four players on the leaderboard have high scores of 100, 90, 90, and 80. Those players will have ranks 1, 2, 2, and 3, respectively. If Alice's scores are 70, 80 and 105, her rankings after each game are 4th, 3rd and 1st.
>
> Function Description
>
> Complete the climbingLeaderboard function in the editor below. It should return an integer array where each element represents Alice's rank after the game.
>
> climbingLeaderboard has the following parameter(s):
>
> scores: an array of integers that represent leaderboard scores
>   alice: an array of integers that represent Alice's scores

MY LOGIC=**Here I first removed the recurring numbers in `scores` array, then I checked where the elements in `alice` array would rank if it is included in scores array**

```
def climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice):

    for i in range(0,len(scores)-1):
        for j in  range(1,len(scores)-i-1):
            if scores[i]==scores[i+j]:
                scores.remove(scores[i+j])
    for k in range(0,len(alice)):
        for c in range(0,len(scores)):
            if alice[k]==scores[c]:
                return c+1
            elif alice[k]>scores[0]:
                return 1
            elif alice[k]<min(scores):
                return len(scores)+1
            elif alice[k]<scores[c] and alice[k]>scores[c+1]:
                return c+2
```

Comment: Hi -- could you format your code please, also show us what it does when you run it.

Comment: I have formatted can you please look the code and find why it is showing "int objects are non interable"

Comment: Well, I'm not going to just answer this because you demand it ;-) Anyway, this can't be answered without more information. Show us what `scores` and `alice` are, the full and exact error message you get, and what you expect it to do.

Comment: I have copied the question can you plz find the error

Comment: Error it is showing is"int object is not iterable"

Comment: SO is not a "do my homework" service. You can learn to help yourself for example by following this: "How to debug small programs" https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ -- further demands that people just "find the error" will lead to my downvoting this question.